# Remove page on Big Cartel using SnakeBite theme

Tags: bigcartel

I would like to know if there is an option to hide/remove the “products” page. I would like that my items are only accessible to shop from the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to go Customize Design > Advanced
And then Edit your Layout Header code.